# Update position in HTML DOM using Knockout jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

In my html page I use knockout to show a section of div:

```
data-bind="visible: showDiv"
```

When this div is shown I would like the  page to scroll down to show it, because at the moment you can't see it appear because it is at the bottom.

See the fiddle, click the Notes with the caret, you'll see that it will appear but the user doesn't know.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5BAB9/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/5BAB9/4/)***

When your note is opened,

```
self.showAddSection = function () {
}
```

scroll to the bottom of the page.

```
$(window).scrollTop($(document).height());
```

End result

```
self.showAddSection = function () {
    if (self.changed){
        self.showAdd(false);
    }else{
        self.showAdd(true); 
        $(window).scrollTop($(document).height());
    }
    self.changed = !self.changed;
}
```

Comment: cheers, I thought scrollTop was what I was looking for, however, didnt know how to implement it